# Creating C# project template from existing one in Powershell/MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

Visual Studio allows to create project template from existing one. I wonder if there's an option to do the same by some powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t create project by using powershell script. You need to create projects programmatically in vs extension/add-in. Check this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228767(v=vs.120).aspx